# Effect every 3rd element/div

Tags: html, css

I've tried adding an element in my CSS to remove the margin-right of every third div. Just seems to be effecting the 3rd and 7th for some reason though. Need it to work on 3rd, 6th, 9th etc...

CSS

```
.shopping-product { background-color: #fff; position: relative; border: 1px solid #eee; width: 200px; height: 250px; margin-right: 20px; float: left; padding-bottom: 20px; }
.shopping-product:nth-child(4n) { margin-right: 0; }
```

Is (4n) correct for every 3rd div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `3n` instead which will select 3rd,6th,9th,....

```
.shopping-product:nth-child(3n) { margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: Thought it would be 3n but nah, effecting 2nd, 5th and 8th. Heres a live url: http://bit.ly/1dpmqn9

Comment: @tokyodrift Just so you know: `:nth-child()` works in ie9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child || If the website has a heavy traffic of ie8 users, you might want to consider making a javascript fallback.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a standard javascript script commonly used of which you could point me to, or does it differ site to site?

Comment: @tokyodrift Since you are already using jquery, you could do something like this: `$("div:nth-child(3n)").addClass("everyThird");` Of course you should probably make sure that the code is only triggered for ie8 and later.